# How to reduce unnecessary space in div with wrapped word

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a small div with fixed width and height, inside i have text, that could be probably wrapped and icon
All i need is to keep icon as close as possible to text, but if text is wrapped it will have extra space inside it

Example at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t39j322a/5/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
         Total elements
    </div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.title {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the icon to be outside the border?

Comment: your requirement is not clear. however are you talking about position absolute ??

Comment: reduce the width of div

Comment: add to the title class the width:70px; Then the space between text and icon is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Grid system:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0em;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Cool, really simple solution, i don`t need ie8 support, so it really works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1:** 
Well. To answer your question, you can straight ahead apply width to the `.title`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.title {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 58px;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Total elements
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

But I would suggest that you use float instead of flex model with the below solution

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.title {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px;
}

.icon {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.title, .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">
    Total elements
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i have to make wrapper with fixed width, and title in some translations could have different width, so i can`t make it fixed width as well

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
         Total elements
    </div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper
{
}
.title {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon 
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```